# Postgres 11 - COMMIT Procedure

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, postgresql-11

With the recent update of [Postres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1855/). It now supports stored procedures. Transactions are finally supported in stored procedures in Postgres. However, I have been trying to perform a commit within a procedure with no luck.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_update(
        IN pid character,
        IN pcategoryname character varying,
        IN pwebcode character varying,
        IN porder numeric,
        IN pupdatedby character varying,
        IN pupdateddate timestamp without time zone,
        IN plang character varying,
        INOUT cresults refcursor)
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE

      cnt bigint;
      rtnCode char(1);

    BEGIN
     cresults := 'cur';

        BEGIN
        update test_table
        set  FCATEGORYNAME   = pCategoryName,
             FWEBCODE        = pWebCode,
             FORDER          = pOrder,
             FUPDATEDBY      = pUpdatedBy,
             FUPDATEDDATE    = pUpdatedDate,
             FLANGCODE       = pLang
        where lower(FID) = lower(pId);
        COMMIT;
        end;
      .
      .
      EXCEPTION WHEN ....
      .
      .
     OPEN cresults FOR VALUES ('stringresult'); 

    end;
    $BODY$;
```

**UPDATED**
Edited so that the Update and Commit is within a block that does not have any exception.

This was previously used to execute the procedure. I was able to fetch the result of the refcursor. Does not work anymore after the commit is added.:

```
begin;
CALL testupdate('ad3caecb-9235-4945-b37a-9b7ff89fdfe0','aa','138',0,'test','2018/06/29 18:04:03','zh-cn','');
fetch all in cur;
commit;
```

but when i execute with:

```
CALL testupdate('ad3caecb-9235-4945-b37a-9b7ff89fdfe0','aa','138',0,'test','2018/06/29 18:04:03','zh-cn','');
```

.. it runs fine and the row got updated, but this way of running doesnt allow me to fetch the result my refcursor.

Is there any way to get the result of my refcursor when excuting a procedure with COMMIT. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And which exception in throws exactly?

Comment: Exception: SQL Error: invalid transaction termination at line 19 COMMIT

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/plpgsql-transactions.html): "*A transaction cannot be ended inside a block with exception handlers.*" - you need to put the `update` and `commit` into a block without an exception handler (currently your procedure is a single block that has an exception handler)

Comment: Okay removing the exeption does work if i run "Call <proc>"  alone, Thanks!, But when i run "begin; Call <proc>; fetch all in cur; commit;" the same exception error appears. I have to call it the latter way to get the result of the cur. is this possible?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your input. i have updated my question

Comment: Read https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/pg-phriday-stored-procedures-postgres-11/

Regarding the invalid transaction termination error, it says that "Apparently CALL is only valid within its own context ... The resulting error is a bit ambiguous however; why is the transaction termination invalid? Can’t it just say we can’t close the current transaction from within a procedure?"